# Can you bridge off of a 240 V Breaker Box that connects to an Intermatic Timer?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power, safety, circuit-breaker

I have an [Intermatic T104 Timer](https://www.intermatic.com/en/Timer-Controls/Mechanical-Time-Switches/T104) drawing power from a [Homeline Breaker Box](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/HOM612L100RB/load-center-hom-mlo-240v-100a-1ph-6sp/)
for a home swimming pool. I'm wondering whether it would be considered safe to use the knockout in the timer enclosure to bridge from the 240 V coming from the breaker box into an Arduino Uno reading data from a pressure transducer.

That is, 240 Volts from the breaker box into the timer, and then tap from the timer into an Arduino Uno. The only load on the Arduino side would be a pressure transducer and a wireless WiFi shield, and I could connect to a common ground in the timer.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jamie, and welcome to the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. A schematic of the circuit you are trying to design would be very helpful for other members wishing help you.

Comment: I believe it is permissible to extend the circuit that feeds the timer by wiring through the timer box to a 240-volt receptacle that is suitably rated for the branch circuit breaker. It is not permissible to power a home-made device except through a cord and plug connection. Even then, it should be plugged in only when supervised by the builder. Home projects are more appropriately powered by purchased power supplies that are listed and labelled by a nationally recognized testing laboratory.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you cannot connect a 240V input power supply to the output of the timer.

the T104 motor operates from 207 to 277 volts so there may be no neutral present thus a 120V power supply may not be usable.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I could just use a 120-240 V wall power supply for an Arduino. I can just open it up, remove the components, and solder them onto my own PCB, which will go into the Arduino.

Alternatively, I could skip the timer all together: I could put a new breaker into the Homeline Box, and bring voltage out of that into the Arduino.

Does that sound like it would work?

Comment: dunno for sure the actual electricians seem to hang out in http://diy.stackexchange.com not here so much.